# Count number of next cells based on criteria

Tags: excel

Can we have a formula or a VBA code for counting number of next cells based on criteria.

For instance if we have a list

```
A
A
B
A
C
```

and we would like to count number of A's after A (the criteria), so in this case, it would be 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to know the number of times `A` is followed by `A` then you can use a formula like this

```
=COUNTIFS(A1:A5,"A",A2:A6,"A")
```

Assuming your data is in `A1:A5`

This will also allow you to find out how many times `A` is followed by `B` or any other combination by changing the criteria

Answer (score 1):

Use SUMPRODUCT():

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A$1:$A$5="A")*($A$2:$A$6=$A$1:$A$5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked, just one thing.. what if i want to how many B's after A's?

Comment: @madyykk I would use callumDA33 answer.  It is better.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest possible solution that I can think for this problem is

```
=IF(A2<>A1,0,INDEX(MATCH(FALSE,A2:A100=A1,0),1,1)-1)
```

[image]